# Google Calender thr VBA, figure out why I am getting event not found error

Tags: vba, google-api, google-calendar-api, webrequest

URL - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

I am using Microsfot Internet Transfer Control and I am trying to send a request 
to delete events in google calendar using eventID instead of entryID.

This is the code that I have used,

```
strURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"
strFormData = "Email=" & myEmail & "&Passwd=" & myPassword & "&source=" & mySource & 
"&service=cl"
strHeaders = "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Inet1.Execute strURL, "POST", strFormData, strHeaders

'Wait for the server response must include the authentication mode
 Responded = False
 Do Until Responded = True
   DoEvents
 Loop

'Ensure that the password is correct for Google
 If InStr(response, "BadAuthentication") Then    'If the password is not Correct
   MsgBox "Google has rejected the password. Confirm the e-mail and password and try 
   again.", vbCritical, "Error"
   Exit Sub
 End If

'Delete Event  
AuthCode = Right(response, Len(response) - InStrRev(response, "Auth=") - 4)
strURL = "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private 
/full/NXZmcjNqM3ZpMnJuaW5hMnVocGM3bWgwbDAgaW50ZWxsaXNvZnR0ZWFtQG0"
strHeaders = "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=" & AuthCode & _
"Content-Type:application/atom+xml"
Responded = False
Inet1.Execute strURL, "Delete", "", strHeaders

Do Until Responded = True
   DoEvents
Loop
```

But, I am getting response as "No events found" (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found), 
but I have event in calendar with the eventID that I have provided in url.

I am unable to figure out why I am getting event not found error.

Answer (score 1):

You should neither use client login, nor use the /feeds/ url as both are deprecated and the latter will be shut down in November this year. Please migrate to API v3 and repost your question if you still have issues. The documentation is at: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar

Comment: Can we use Google Calendar API v3 in Access VBA? It seems there is no way to use this in VBA. Do we need to develop it in .net?

Comment: Here is a sample code for VB using the client library: http://samples.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp/README.html

Comment: Thanks, but it's in vb.net, I am looking for Visual Basic for Applications(VBA) code sample , which can be done in Microsoft Access.